# Cocos2d sprite's parent not reflecting true scale value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am encountering issues with determining a CCSprite's parent node's scale value.

In my game I have a class that extends CCLayer and scales itself based on game triggers. Certain child sprites of this CCLayer have mathematical calculations that become inaccurate once I scale the parent CCLayer. For instance, I have a tank sprite that needs to determine its firing point within the parent node.

Whenever I scale the layer and ask the layer for its scale values, they are accurate. However, when I poll the sprites contained within the layer for their parent's scale values, they always appear as one.

```
// From within the sprite
CCLOG(@"ChildSprite-> Parent's scale values are scaleX: %f, scaleY: %f",
      self.parent.scaleX, self.parent.scaleY); // Outputs 1.0,1.0

// From within the layer
CCLOG(@"Layer-> ScaleX : %f, ScaleY: %f , SCALE: %f",
      self.scaleX, self.scaleY,     self.scale); // Output is 0.80,0.80
```

Could anyone explain to me why this is the case? I don't understand why these values are different. Maybe I don't understand the inner design of Cocos2d fully. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is the code I am using to insert a sprite into the layer

```
EarthTank * earthTank = [[EarthTank alloc] initWithWorld:self->world  
atLocation:spawnPointRight withID:pid];
earthTank.tankShaft = shaft; 
[earthTank createInitialArsenal:tempPlayer];
[earthTank addAndAlignTankShaft];
[spriteBatchNode addChild:earthTank z:2];
```

So the problem is self.parent (called within sprite) references the SpriteBatchNode and not the layer itself. If you change the call to self.parent.parent you can find the Layer's true scale values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like self.parent isn't actually the layer. Check that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could this have something to do with the fact I am using a spritBatchNode? This would mean the parent is the spriteBatchNode which would have a scale of 1

Comment: Okay changed the calls to self.parent.parent and the scales are reflected accurately. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Every CCNode has an independent scale, but the scale from parent down (nested) is cumulative.

Eg. A parents scale will effect all objects that are its decedent, but a child will not effect its parent.

For example if a parent layer is scaled at 50%, then all the children will have the 50% factored in when they display, even if the scaling for the individual object is 100%.

Math being,   0.50 * 1.00  = 0.50